# Can't main thread with SCHED_OTHER create threads with SCHED_FIFO or SCHED_RR?

Tags: linux, pthreads, scheduling

I have made a multi-thread application with <pthread.h>

and I've tried creating a thread with SCHED_FIFO(real-time scheduling policy)..

```
(pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attr, SCHED_RR);
pthread_create(&t_ID, &attr, thread_func, (void*) t )   );
```

When the main thread's policy was `SCHED_OTHER`, `pthread_create()` returned `error(INVALID ATTR)`.

But, when I set main thread's policy to be `SCHED_FIFO`(or `SCHED_RR`), `pthread_create()` successfully created SCHED_FIFO(or SCHED_RR) thread..

**Can't main thread with normal scheduling policy create new thread with Real-Time scheduling policy??**

Thank you.

Comment: Are you also setting the scheduling priority among the attributes of the new thread?  Realtime scheduling policies (`SCHED_FIFO` and `SCHED_RR`) require non-zero priority.  Ordinary scheduling policies such as `SCHED_OTHER` require priority 0.  Perhaps you're trying to set a realtime policy on a new thread that is inheriting its scheduling priority from its creator.

Comment: @John Bollinger Oh sorry. I forgot to say about that.
I also set pthread_attr variable with sched_priority=30(,5, 50 etc..), and pthread_setinheritsched = PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED..
When main thread is set to SCHED_FIFO or SCHED_RR, newly created thread succefully had a scheduling policy different from main thread.. But, when main thread is set to SCHED_OTHER, main couldn't create new threads with realtime policy. I've found some manpage(sched, pthread_setschedpolicy etc..) but I can't found any mention that SCHED_OTHER can't create REALTIME policies.

Comment: Oh. I noticed newly created threads inherit the same priority as main thread despite PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED. It seemed that since SCHED_OTHER thread's priority is fixed to 0, main thread with SCHED_OTHER can't create real-time policy thread, which have priority higher than 0. Is anyone who knows some references about this?

Comment: MY PROBLEM IS SOLVED..! my simple mistake : attempt to set priority higher than 0 before changing the scheduling policy to real-time policy..

Comment: I'm glad you got it working.  I'm sure that anyone who comes upon this question later would most appreciate a self answer providing details of what you ended up doing.